# Why is it that when I alias a command, running the alias limits the output? How do I make it return the full output?

Tags: shell, zsh

When I run `history` in zsh, I get back thousands of lines.

When I alias `history` and run `history`, I get fewer than thousands of lines outputed.

```bsh
(myenv) alias history='history'
(myenv) history
10119* alias history='history'
10120  history
10121  man alias
10122  history
10123* alias -p history='history'
10124* alias -p
10125* man history
10126* history man
10127* man ls
10128* man history
10129  alias history='history'
10130  history
10131  alias history='history' && history
10132  unalias history
10133  history
10134  alias history='history'
```

How do I make my alias return the full output? I am trying to make a more complicated alias and this behavior is giving me problems with the actual alias I'm trying to set. There's no reason for me to make an alias for command `history` called `history`.

I am using a iTerm2 and zsh on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: `history` was an alias before, probably something like `fc -l 1`. Check with `which history`.

Comment: @myp, you are correct. `alias history='echo nb that history can be cleaned up at $HISTFILE && omz_history'` works. 
Thank you.

If you make your comment an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer.